# Not loading ArrayList from txt file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am attempting to populate an ArrayList from a text file that I am able to populate. I am trying to pull the objects at [0] and [1] and running them through a method. What I'm unsure of is whether or not I am loading the file incorrectly or if I'm just trying to pull the elements incorrectly. The method I am putting arguments into does work when I create the objects individually. Below is my main trying to run the method and my load file. Any help would be appreciated.

Text file contents

```
Ryu Balance 50 50 40 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0
Ken Balance 50 50 40 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at Roster.loadFromFile(Roster.java:33)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Roster roster = new Roster();
        roster.loadFromFile();

        Battle.match(roster.get(0), roster.get(1), 180);
    }
}
```

Import file

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//A class meant for building and populating a roster
public class Roster {

    ArrayList<Hero> heroList;

    public Roster () {
        heroList = new ArrayList<Hero>();
    }
    public void loadFromFile() {

        Scanner inFS = null;
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;

        try{
            // open the File and set delimiters
            fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("Roster.txt");
            inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
            inFS.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");
            inFS.nextLine();

            // continue while there is more data to read
            while(inFS.hasNext()) {

                // read four data elements
                String name = inFS.next();

                String fightStyle = inFS.next();
                int hitPoints = inFS.nextInt();
                int stamina = inFS.nextInt();
                int mana = inFS.nextInt();
                int dodgeBlock = inFS.nextInt();
                int[] statBlock = new int[12];
                statBlock[0] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[1] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[2] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[3] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[4] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[5] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[6] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[7] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[8] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[9] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[10] = inFS.nextInt();
                statBlock[11] = inFS.nextInt();

                int win = inFS.nextInt();
                int draw = inFS.nextInt();
                int loss = inFS.nextInt();

                Hero hero = new Hero(name, fightStyle, hitPoints, stamina, mana, dodgeBlock, statBlock, win, draw, loss);
                //TO DO: instantiate an object of the Hero class
                heroList.add(hero);
                //TO DO: add object to the collection (heroList)
            }
            fileByteStream.close();

            // error while reading the file
        }catch(IOException error1) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Error related to: Character.dat" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: ... What problem do you observe?

Comment: You should try debugging this first before coming to stack overflow. Not only that, but for us to help you, we'd also need more informtion like what is in your text file

Comment: Please edit your post and add the problem. Also add the contents of the file exactly you have including spaces, new line.

Comment: Edited initial post for more relevant information (my bad)

Comment: Your deliminator pattern appears to be limited to commas and end of line characters but your data is space-separated.  Which line is Roster:33?

Comment: If you get rid of: `inFS.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");` **and** get rid of `inFS.nextLine();`, then your code should have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

After taking in what @vsfDawg had said the issue was the delimiter.

I changed the delimiter to "[\s\n]+" to take into account both the space and next line. In addition I ran into a new problem in which it would only read my second line. Therefore I removed the first inFS.nextLine() before the try actually begins.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: This should of been an Update Edit in your original post.